# Retrieve data from json using Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to retrieve the urls from the sub elements given comp1 and comp2 as input to the python script

```
{
  "main1": {
    "comp1": {
      "url": [
        "http://kcdclcm.com",
        "http://dacklsd.com"
       ]
    },
    "comp2": {
      "url": [
           "http://dccmsdlkm.com",
           "http://clsdmcsm.com"
        ]
    }
  },
  "main2": {
    "comp3": {
      "url": [
        "http://csdc.com",
        "http://uihjkn.com"
       ]
    },
    "comp4": {
      "url": [
           "http://jkll.com",
           "http://ackjn.com"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Following is the snippet of the python function, I am trying to use to grab the urls

```
import json
data = json.load(open('test.json'))
def geturl(comp):
    if comp in data[comp]:
        for url in data[comp]['url']:
            print url
geturl('comp1')
geturl('comp2')
```

I totally understand the error is in the 4th and 5th line of the script, since i am trying to grab the url information from the second element of the json data without passing the first element 'main1' or 'main2'. Same script works fine if I replace the 4th and 5th line as below:

```
if comp in data['main1']:
    for url in data['main1'][comp]['url']:
```

In my case, i would not know main1 and main2 as the user would just pass comp1, comp2, comp3 and comp4 part as input to the script. Is there a way to find the url information given that only the second element is known

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the keys/values in the dict to check if the second level key you are searching for is present:

```
import json

data = json.load(open('test.json'))

def geturl(comp):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if comp in v and 'url' in v[comp]:
            print "%s" % "\n".join(v[comp]['url'])

geturl('comp1')
geturl('comp2')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search the urls with only comp key in every main, you just need to do it like this:

```
import json
data = json.load(open('test.json'))
def geturl(comp):
    for mainKey in data:
        main = data[mainKey]
        if comp in main:
            urls = main[comp]['url']
            for url in urls:
                print url

geturl('comp1')
geturl('comp2')
```